# CGAffineTransform block others animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have two images(iphoneImage , ipadImage) and i want to move ipadImage and rotate iphoneImage but when i use CGAffineTransform on iphoneImage it blocks ipadImage Move ??
so any suggestions

```
 CGRect tempRect=CGRectMake(-351, self.ipadImage.frame.origin.y,
                           self.ipadImage.frame.size.width,
                           self.ipadImage.frame.size.height);
CGAffineTransform transform=_iphoneImage.transform;
 transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI * 90 / 180.0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                 animations:^{
                     _ipadImage.frame=tempRect;
                     _iphoneImage.transform=transform;
                 }];
```

Comment: Do you use both images in both versions? Isn't it better to do a check on which kind of device it is and handle the changing of image / animation like that?

Comment: I don't see how the iPhoneImage would change under any circumstances.  The code posted doesn't modify it's transform.

Comment: danh
_iphoneImage.transform=transform; --> this changes transform of _iphoneImage

Comment: jasper pol
it is just name for images not versions